# How can I calculate the difference between rows in a column?

Tags: text-processing

If I have the below output. A column with 8 rows:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

And I want an output with something like this.

```
1-3 
2-4
3-5
4-6
5-7
6-8
```

Actually, I want only the result of this difference.

Comment: Does `awk '{print $1-$3, $2-$4, $3-$5, $4-$6, $5-$7, $6-$8}'` work? Your question is not very clear.

Comment: You have 8 lines input, 6 lines output. From which criteria you deduce 6 ? Do you mean you want on each output line the number of the current line and the content of the number 2 lines later ? You should really precise what you want.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the actual output you expect if it's now what you currently show as the expected output, i.e. whatever `Actually, I want only the result of this difference.` means. Presumably you don't want 6 lines of `-2` output.

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you're asking for:

```
$ seq 8 | awk -v d=2 'NR>d{print a[(NR-d)%d] "-" $0} {a[NR%d]=$0}'
1-3
2-4
3-5
4-6
5-7
6-8
```

or maybe:

```
$ seq 8 | awk -v d=2 'NR>d{print a[(NR-d)%d] - $0} {a[NR%d]=$0}'
-2
-2
-2
-2
-2
-2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk with a loop to calculate the difference:

```
awk '{a[NR]=$1} END {for(i=1;i<=NR-2;i++) print a[i]-a[i+2]}' data.txt
```

This version with quoted minus `"-"` will output the result as `1-3` etc:

```
awk '{a[NR]=$1} END {for(i=1;i<=NR-2;i++) print a[i]"-"a[i+2]}' data.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -e ' my @a = lines(); my @b = @a[2..*]; .put for [Z-] @a, @b;'  file
```

Sample Input:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Sample Output:

```
-2
-2
-2
-2
-2
-2
```

Raku is a programming language in the Perl family. It was first named "Perl6" until 2019, then re-named "Raku". You can find some high level operators in Raku. Above, `lines` are read into `@a` array. Then `@b` array is created by copying over `@a[2..*]` the first array *sans* its first two elements. Finally, data is out`put` using Raku's `[Z]` Z-reduction meta-operator, which takes lists (e.g. `@a` and `@b`) and pulls off individual elements one-by-one, combining them. In this case the combination is directed by the `[Z-]` composite-operator which includes a minus sign. This tells Raku to subtract the second element from the first.

---

For a more interesting list of numbers, try `grep`ping out primes from a list of integers up to 1000. Below with the bare `[Z]` operator shows you the initial result:

```perl
~$ raku -e ' my @a = grep &is-prime, ^1000; my @b = @a[2..*]; .say for [Z] @a[0..7], @b[0..7];' 
(2 5)
(3 7)
(5 11)
(7 13)
(11 17)
(13 19)
(17 23)
(19 29)
```

Now, use the `[Z-]` composite reduction meta-operator instead:

```perl
~$ raku -e ' my @a = grep &is-prime, ^1000; my @b = @a[2..*]; .say for [Z-] @a[0..7], @b[0..7];'
-3
-4
-6
-6
-6
-6
-6
-10
```

https://docs.raku.org/language/operators.html#Reduction_metaoperators
https://docs.raku.org/routine/is-prime.html
https://docs.raku.org/language.html
https://raku.org